# Determining a function given points and slopes

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials, tangent-line

> A polynomial function of degree 2 passes through the point P(1, 3). At this point the
> function’s slope (i.e. the slope of its tangent) is 1 and at the point Q(2, y) it has a
> slope of 5. Determine the function.

I am not sure how to approach this question.  I have found the equation for the tangent lines: *y = x + 2* and *y = 5x - 10 + y* for points P and Q respectively.  I know that the function will have the general form $(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.  However, I am not sure how to implement this information in order to find the function.  I know I am supposed to use derivatives but not quite sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $P(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$. According to the given data, we can conclude that

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
P(1) = a + b + c = 3\\\\
P'(1) = 2a + b = 1\\\\
P'(2) = 4a + b = 5
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so.  I would solve the problem as a system of simultaneous equations.  My only question is why is the second derivative equal to 5?  I thought it would be P'(2) = 2a + b = 5?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was a typo. I meant $P'(2) = 4a + b = 5$.

Comment: No worries.  Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then $a+b+c=3$. $f'(x)=2ax+b$, then $2a+b=1, 4a+b=5 \implies a=2, b=-3$, then $c=4$. So $f(x)=2x^2-3x+4$.

Comment: I think that is supposed to be ()=2^2−3+4 .

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2):

$$
F(x)=ax^2+bx+c\\
F'(x)=2ax+b
$$
At $(1,3)$ we have $F(1,3)=a+b+c=3$ and $F'(1)=2a+b=1$. At $(2,y)$ we have $F'(2)=4a+b=5$
Thus we have 3 equations with 3 unknowns that we can solve to find:
$$
a = 2,\ \  b = -3,\ \  c = 4
$$